Magento 2.4.7 Customer Custom Attribute Value no Change
When I created one Customer Custom Attribute and changed its value website-wise from Admin-> Edit Customer Information so did not change it.
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup\Patch\Data;
    
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute;
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    
    class AddCustomerStatusAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
    {
        private $moduleDataSetup;
    
        private $customerSetupFactory;
    
        public function __construct(
            ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
            CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
        ) {
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
            $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        }
        
        public function apply()
        {
            /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'customer_status',
                [
                    'label' => 'Customer Approve',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 40,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'system' => false,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'default'  => 1,
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    "note"    => "Set Approve to login"
                ]
            );
    
            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'customer_status');
            
            $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
            
            $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $used_in_forms)
                    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                    ->setData("sort_order", 100);
            $attribute->save();
        }
    
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
        public static function getDependencies()
        {
            return [];
        }
    
       /**
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
        public function getAliases()
        {
            return [];
        }
    }


Any one have idea of this?

Magento Known Issue : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/38730
Here you can find the patch :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6db1257dd697af0a206f46bd9de95bd712a178ab

This will be resolved in 2.4.8 as mentioned here https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/magento-open-source/2-4-8
